# Magento title not showing on category view

Tags: magento

On http://www.justdoors.co/vinyl-colours.html for whatever reason the product titles aren't showing.

This is the relevent code from our template/catalog/product/list.phtml file:

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
```

It was working OK in magento 1.5.1 but we've done an update to 1.6.0 and seems to be since that. can anyone shed some light on this problem, I don't seem to be getting and error message so not really sure where to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your variable is just empty. Always look what is inside of your object by dumping it or inspecting it with debugger

```
<?php print_r($_product);?>
```

or if its too large and has many references then try to see object parameters only

```
<?php print_r(array_keys($_product));?>
```

Then you can inspect yourself what variables you can ask directly from object or what you need to query or extend your collections to get by default.

Its worth to look if your product name attribute is enabled for listings (from attribute settings).